# dataGridViewActivity.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex is not working

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want gridview scrollbar to set at last row at gridview. For that purpose, i've used below solution.

```
dataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

But this is not working. When i tried to debug i found that, `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` value gets reset in `dataGridViewActivity_RowStateChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

Set the last row as the first visible row:

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 
dataGridView1.Rows.GetLastRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible);
```

Or set the last visible row as the first visible row:

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 
dataGridView1.Rows.GetLastRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Displayed);
```

Or move to the last selected row if it is not displayed:

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 
    dataGridView1.SelectedRows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count - 1].Index;
}
```